# Access Origin issues in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, iframe, phonegap-build

I'm having issues getting webpages to display in an iframe on a PhoneGap app I am developing.  I'm currently testing the app on iOS.

From what I understand, I have to whitelist certain sites in the config.xml file by using ""

I'm trying to allow users to access login and registration pages through the iframe.  I have the access origin set to the following:

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
```

It loads all the other pages on my site (trying to connect it to http://www.pokemonfriendcodes.com/), but when I click links to go to the login/registration page, it won't load.  The app just does nothing.

Here are two of the pages I need to access that won't load: http://www.pokemonfriendcodes.com/login/
http://www.pokemonfriendcodes.com/register/

Any ideas as to why these won't load?  It seems to be that anything pertaining to the logging in/user-end won't load.

I've tried changing the origin to www.pokemonfriendcodes.com as well and even getting rid of the "subdomains" bit--but no luck.  I thought just leaving it at "*" allowed for it to connect to any webpage, but I guess not...?

Not sure what to do at this point.  Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure that the config setting propagates to iframes. iframes act as their own containers independent of their parent window. Are you able to achieve your desired result without an iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is completely on server side and has nothing to do with the *access origin*.

Problem is the cross-origin policy that your server applies on *login* and *register* pages. You can see it yourself by opening web developer tools and network console from there. After you have network console open, go to your root URL (http://www.pokemonfriendcodes.com/) and check the headers sent by your server. Now, open new tab and do the same thing with login/register page and compare the *response headers*. As you can see there is no `X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN` on root URL headers but it is on login and register pages. This disables it from being shown in your iframe.

To fix this, disable the `X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN` header on those pages too on your server.

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem!